# How to make request and use context without infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, ajax

So I've been practicing React for a couple days now, and I am experimenting using an API.
However, I've run into a problem where React infinitely re-renders a component.

Here is the code:

```
const ContentSidebar = (props) => {
  const recipeCtx = useContext(RecipeContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRecipes = async () => {
      const response = await axios(
        "https://react-http-16b52-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/recipes.json"
      );

      return response.data;
    };

    fetchRecipes().then((recipes) => {
      recipeCtx.setRecipes(recipes); // Method that adds and formats data to recipeCtx.recipes 
    });
  }, [recipeCtx]);

  return (some jsx using recipeCtx.recipes)
};

export default ContentSidebar;
```

What I am thinking happens, is the following:

1. Component renders
2. useEffect is called upon initial render
3. Data is fetched and recipeCtx.setRecipes() is called and **updates** recipeCtx.recipes
4. Context update causes another render
5. Restart from step 1

My question is: How can I use the method to update recipeCtx, but only call a fetch once?
I am aware I can remove the dependencies for useEffect, but I heard it is a bad practice and I am not sure how to go about it, since it also underlines it in VS code.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `recipeCtx` from the `useEffect` dependencies (second argument). Right now your code is saying: "rerun the effect, i.e., fetch and set recipes, whenever recipes change". Well, obviously they change when you fetch and set them, so it just keep running again and again. That's probably not what you want. Just use an empty list for dependencies:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRecipes = async () => {
      ....
  }, []);
```